# Dual Boot and Virtualize the Same Partition- Kali Linux in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot, virtualbox, multi-boot, kali-linux

I am trying to virtualize an existing partition, as detailed in [this](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-and-virtualize-the-same-partition-on-y-493223329) article, as described [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) in the VirtualBox manual. The Kali install is on a logical partition on the same disk as my Windows install. Running diskpart, my Windows install is partition 1, and the Kali install appears twice on the list (not sure why), one is partition 0 labeled extended and the other is partition 2 labeled logical. They are identical in size. Partition 0 seems to be the one that actually works in the next part.

I am able to create the vmdk using `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "C:\Users\(Username)\Desktop\Ubuntu.vmdk" -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive0 -partitions 0` and it additionally creates another vmdk with "-pt" appended to the filename, which I don't understand.

I made a Grub boot.img from within Kali and copied it over to Windows.

I created a new virtual machine for Debian (x64), chose the previously created vmdk for the hard disk, and mounted the boot.img in the vm's CD drive. However, when I boot the vm, it doesn't work. GRUB appears and shows the correct entry, but upon selecting the os, it displays: `error: no such device: 3629c852-5f3e-46ac-85-cd-631a9377cc43.
Loading Linux 3.7-trunk-amd64 ... error:unknown filesystem. Loading initial ramdisk ... error: you need to load the kernel first.`

I tried running some LiveCD utilities through the VM, and they couldn't detect an OS, so there seems to be a problem with the virtual hard disk. Anybody have any suggestions for what could be causing this problem and how I can fix it? I would just move Kali to a VM completely, but I feel like there are more benefits having it available as a dual boot. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!